# GitHub Codespace Logon Script // GitHub Enterprise

Tags: github-enterprise, github-codespaces

I'm using GitHub-Codespaces in an enterprise subscription. The environment is preconfigured with a dev-container: https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/configuring-codespaces-for-your-project

After successful startup, I want to execute a final command on shell, example: `cat /etc/os-release` with a standard output on the user-terminal.

**Since there is no `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in GitHub-Codespaces, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Do you have an idea?**